# EXTJS 6.0.x: Increase space between axis and axis label

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I'm using extjs 6.0.1. We want to increase the space between the axis and axis labels both (x&y axis).

Any help here would be great.

[image: Increase distance between axis & axis label]

Comment: the title label you could use the axis property 'title Margin' to adjust the space

Answer (score 1):

Just use **titleMargin** config in the axis:

```
          axes: [{
                type: 'numeric',
                title: 'My Title',
                titleMargin: 100,
                fields: ['field1', 'field2'],
                position: 'left',
                grid: true
            }, {
                type: 'category',
                title: 'Period',
                titleMargin: 100,
                position: 'bottom',
                fields: 'period_field',
                label: {
                    rotate: {
                        degrees: -45
                    }
                }                    
            }]
```